# Parse HTML in C# without AgilityPack

Tags: html, .net, html-parsing

I have a HTML file, with several input fields some with an id, loaded into a C# string:

```
<div>
   <input id="inpName" type="text" />
   <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Lets say I want to add an required attribute to the input with the id *inpName*.

In jQuery I would do:

```
$('input#inpName').prop('required', true);
```

**Q**: How can I achieve add this attribute without adding the HTMLAgilyPack?

Can I use **XmlDocument** or my only choice are **regular expressions** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use XML objects

like in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.aspx

and use the XMLNode object to take what you want
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlNode.aspx

you can use expressions to search what you want
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

you can use this code to get a NODE

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXMLContent); 
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("MYTAG");
```

Comment: If I use XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.LoadXml(source); I get this error *Name cannot begin with the '0' character, hexadecimal value 0x30. Line 66, position 11.* On line 66 I have JS code : if(diff<0)

Comment: i'm using this code to get a NODE

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXMLContent); 
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("MYTAG");

Comment: @misi - yes, that's why the Html Agility Pack exists. If you can't use it, you'll have to do the parsing manually or using a regex. But that's not easy in the general case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: this HTML changes? you  cant use a simple replace of <input id="inpName" type="text" /> to <input id="inpName" type="text" required="true" /> ??

Comment: so you suggest using the C# string.Replace(). Or the Regex.Replace()